# How to use multiple audio outputs from one device

Tags: macos, audio

I have an USB Interface with 16 in and outs. Now i would like to send all my system sound to output 1,2 and 7,8. I could only select one pair in the "Audio Midi Setup" --> Configure Speaker.

There are some tools like, Loopback but i don't like to have an "virtual" audio out. i only want to use my interface with multiple outputs.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What precisely is the interface, & have you referred to the manufacturer for info? 16ch USB interfaces generally don't fall into the consumer realm & need specific drivers.

Comment: When you use Audio MIDI setup to aggregate devices, you're still creating a virtual audio out.  In fact, everything you see is virtual since macOS doesn't allow you direct access to the hardware.

Comment: I use an Presonus 1818VSL

Comment: I like the Idea of an aggregate device, but also there, I can't select my interface twice.

Comment: I've used Presonus for court reporting, albeit in Windows.  You should use their software to create the channels you need.

Comment: https://www.presonus.com/products/AudioBox-1818VSL/downloads